# jquery to create advanced search query builder

Tags: jquery, search, constructor

I am a newbie with javascript programming, but I found this javascript (MooTools) based query constructor very useful to implement in the website I am working on.

The live implementation can be found here http://opl.bibliocommons.com/search

I believe the same functionality is possible to achieve using jquery. I am looking at pointers on how to start! For e.g the MooTools integrated js file instantiates a new Class and binds events to various form elements. How should this be replaced if I am using jquery?

Appreciate your ideas.

Balu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can duplicate class functionality in jQuery and then bind events to different form elements just the same, you just need to get the syntax right:

```
$(function(){

Init = new function(){
    this.construct = function(){
        Actions.bind();
    }
}

Actions = new function(){
    this.bind = function(){
        $("#selector1").bind("click", function(){
            Actions.doActions();
        });

        $("#selector2").bind("change", function(){
            Actions.doActions();
        });
    }

    this.doActions = function(){
        //Do generic stuff here
    }
}

Init.construct();

});
```

Comment: thank you matt. It gets me started in the right direction. To extend it further, how do I call a generic function to bind the selector? For e.g whatever stuff I do in the click of selector1, I need to do on the change event of a drop down box.

Comment: Call a function within the action of the selector. Edited answer to demonstrate.

Comment: thanks again.I am facing another challenge now. There is a div with a dropdown, a textbox and an anchor. This div with the controls has to be dynamically created on click of "Add more" button. Once the new div is created, I need to bind events to controls inside the div.

Comment: The attached code is the add_query_part: function in js file http://appserver6.static.bibliocommons.com/javascripts/bc/AdvancedSearch.js?1292369589

Comment: No problem although you probably want to start a new question with your latest challenge in order to get the widest range of participants. This question will feature quite low down the listings now so you won't get the expertise you need. If you are happy with the previous answer, mark it as answered (you should always do this if you receive a satisfactory answer) and then start a new question and you'll see a bigger response from the community.